# Linq to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

`dtQuestMembers` - таблица

```cs
var exist = (from row in dtQuestMembers.AsEnumerable() 
             where row.Field<int>(ConsularFormFields.Fields.ROLEINQUESTID) 
                   == RoleInQuest.SPOUSE 
             select row).ToList().Count == 1
```

не работает `ToList()` то же самое `Count() == 1`

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Заданное приведение является недопустимым.'
```

Просто сделать выборку дает, но мне нужно именно количество

Comment: А вы уверены, что оно даёт сделать выборку? `LINQ` же "ленивый". Реальные вычисления делаются когда вы что-то с результатом будете делать. Ну или в список превратите, например.  Так, а какого типа у вас в реальности поле `ConsularFormFields.Fields.ROLEINQUESTID` в `dtQuestMembers`? Может оно не `int` и не может быть приведено к `int`?

Comment: Чтобы посчитать количество записей, не обязательно преобразовывать результат в список. Нужно составить запрос так, чтобы он возвращал количество записей.

Comment: AsEnumerable() здесь точно надо?

Comment: RoleInQuestId Int всегда

Comment: Посмотрите каким типом у вас является exist